# How can I read only first row from an Excel file with OleDbDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Can anybody help me?
How can I read only first row from an Excel file with OleDbDataAdapter?

I know how I can read all data from any spread sheet:

```
var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "$]", oledbConnection);
```

But I don't know how can I do this for one row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select top 1 * from ...
```

Comment: that's just very basic sql actually ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to a range:

```
var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "$A1:C2]", oledbConnection);
```